# How to know how many rows and columns are selected in a NSMatrix?

Tags: cocoa, nsmatrix

How to know how many rows and columns are selected in a NSMatrix ? I tried many things but it does not work.

I thought about first getting the selected cells by calling `selectedCells` method of `NSMatrix` but then I don't know what to do. I should save somewhere in each cell instance its position (row/col) inside the `NSMatrix`? Is there another solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can find out how many are selected by doing this:

```
NSArray *selectedArray = [myMatrix selectedCells];
NSUInteger selectedNum = [selectedArray count];
```

Where `myMatrix` is your `NSMatrix` instance.

Comment: This is what I did but I don't know separately how many rows and cols are selected

Comment: Hmmm, not sure if that's possible. I'm not too familiar with `NSMatrix`.